# Optimization of a Recursive SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a large table that I need to update. It is defined by the following example (but mine is truly massive 1M+ rows and more columns)...

```
CREATE TABLE T
    ([Errors] varchar(4), [MRN] int, [EPI] varchar(13), [WD] varchar(4));

INSERT INTO T
    ([Errors], [MRN], [EPI], [WD])
VALUES
(NULL, 107, 'IP00001070001', 'AMUM'),
(NULL, 107, 'IP00001070001', 'AMUM'),
(NULL, 107, 'IP00001070001', 'KNAP'),
(NULL, 107, 'IP00001070002', 'KNAP'),
(NULL, 107, 'IP00001070002', 'KNAP'),
(NULL, 107, 'IP00001070002', 'KNAP'),
(NULL, 107, 'IP00001070002', 'KNAP'),
(NULL, 381, 'IP00003810001', 'EAUS'),
(NULL, 381, 'IP00003810001', 'EAUS'),
(NULL, 381, 'IP00003810003', 'DOCK'),
(NULL, 381, 'IP00003810003', NULL),
(NULL, 45, 'IP00000450001', 'ASES'),
('__', 45, 'IP00000450002', NULL),
('__', 381, 'IP00003810002', NULL);
```

I need to update the WD columns of those records that have null WD values to match the WD value of the first entry if they were ordered by [MRN] and [EPI]. For example, the required output would be:

```
Errors  MRN EPI             WD
NULL    107 IP00001070001   AMUM
NULL    107 IP00001070001   AMUM
NULL    107 IP00001070001   KNAP
NULL    107 IP00001070002   KNAP
NULL    107 IP00001070002   KNAP
NULL    107 IP00001070002   KNAP
NULL    107 IP00001070002   KNAP
NULL    381 IP00003810001   EAUS
NULL    381 IP00003810001   EAUS
NULL    381 IP00003810003   EAUS
NULL    381 IP00003810003   EAUS
NULL    45  IP00000450001   ASES
__      381 IP00003810003   EAUS
__      45  IP00000450002   ASES
__      381 IP00003810002   EAUS
```

With the edited records at the bottom. This is what I want. However, this method is SLLLLOOOOWWW... Very slow, and for good reason, I am looping over the the entire set. My questions are having already indexed the target table:

1. How can I optimize this query/operation?
2. Do I even need recursion here?

Here is the entire test query set to aid anyone who is willing to help:

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT name 
    FROM sys.tables 
    WHERE name = N'T')
DROP TABLE [T] 
GO

CREATE TABLE T
    ([Errors] varchar(4), [MRN] int, [EPI] varchar(13), [WD] varchar(4));

INSERT INTO T
    ([Errors], [MRN], [EPI], [WD])
VALUES
    (NULL, 107, 'IP00001070001', 'AMUM'),
    (NULL, 107, 'IP00001070001', 'AMUM'),
    (NULL, 107, 'IP00001070001', 'KNAP'),
    (NULL, 107, 'IP00001070002', 'KNAP'),
    (NULL, 107, 'IP00001070002', 'KNAP'),
    (NULL, 107, 'IP00001070002', 'KNAP'),
    (NULL, 107, 'IP00001070002', 'KNAP'),
    (NULL, 381, 'IP00003810001', 'EAUS'),
    (NULL, 381, 'IP00003810001', 'EAUS'),
    (NULL, 381, 'IP00003810003', 'DOCK'),
    (NULL, 381, 'IP00003810003', 'DOCK'),
    (NULL, 45, 'IP00000450001', 'ASES'),
    ('__', 381, 'IP00003810003', NULL),
    ('__', 45, 'IP00000450002', NULL),
    ('__', 381, 'IP00003810002', NULL);

IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
           FROM sys.indexes 
           WHERE name='idxEETEST' AND object_id = OBJECT_ID('T'))
DROP INDEX [idxEETEST] ON [T];
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idxEpiIPWardLoad] 
ON [T] ([MRN], [EPI])
GO

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @mrn INT
DECLARE @epi NVARCHAR(16)
DECLARE @get_rec CURSOR
SET @get_rec = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT MRN, EPI 
    FROM T 
    WHERE Errors IS NOT NULL
OPEN @get_rec
FETCH NEXT
FROM @get_rec INTO @mrn, @epi 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql = 
        'DECLARE @wd VARCHAR(4); ' +
        'SELECT TOP 1 @wd = WD ' + 
        'FROM T ' + 
        'WHERE MRN = ' + Convert(VARCHAR, @mrn) + ';' +
        'UPDATE T ' +
        'SET WD = @wd ' + 
        'WHERE MRN = ' + Convert(VARCHAR, @mrn) + ' AND EPI = ''' + @epi + ''''
    EXEC(@sql);

    FETCH NEXT
    FROM @get_rec INTO @mrn, @epi 
END
CLOSE @get_rec
DEALLOCATE @get_rec
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
           FROM sys.indexes 
           WHERE name='idxEETEST' AND object_id = OBJECT_ID('T'))
DROP INDEX [idxEETEST] ON [T];
GO
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why are you using a loop with dynamic sql for an update? This could be rewritten as a single update statement with no dynamic sql or looping at all.

Comment: Because I am rusty as hell and was struggling to see how I could get the first record of a batch to update the same table without recursion. Any help would be greatly received.

Comment: I don't quite follow the logic of what you are trying to accomplish here. Can you explain the business rules?

Comment: @SeanLange thanks for your response. The logic is as follows, any record with Error as NOT NULL needs it's WD column updating. The WD column should be updated using the record with the same MRN and lowest EPI value. So fo MRN = 45, the record with EPI = 'IP00000450002' is updated from 'IP00000450001', for MRN = 381, both EPI = 'IP00003810003' and 'IP00003810002' get their WD value from 'IP00003810001'. I hope this clarifies things...

Comment: When insert process, DO update process. The performance will be more.

Comment: @NEER they already have a table filled with data. Of course it would be better to do this when inserting but the inserts have already happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you are trying to do. It would help considerably if you posted what you expect as desired output so I could confirm. But with the rules and data posted this should work.

```
update t1 set WD = u.NewWD
FROM T t1
cross apply
(
    select top 1 WD as NewWD
    from T t2
    where t2.MRN = t1.MRN
    order by t2.EPI
)u
where t1.Errors is not null
```

Comment: Will be cumbersome for a big table.

Answer (score 0):

Still I am not clear about your query. But still if you want to use the same query, you can consider following improvements.

1) Why are you doing the data conversion to varchar. The conversion is done at 2 places and, if it's removed it will improve performance.(Hope conversion is not required)

2) The indexes - As you are filtering based on 'MRN' and 'EPI', if you have 2 indexes for each filtering as

i) CREATE INDEX index_name ON table_name (MRN)

ii) CREATE INDEX index_name ON table_name (MRN, EPI)

That also improve your performance

Comment: But indexing isn't the problem here. The real performance sink is the cursor.